# Zabbix : Ping time to a zabbix agent?

Tags: monitoring, ping, zabbix

Can i found with zabbix when it use ping to a zabbix agent :

- number of packet lost
- ping time

I used the item ping.agent but it returns me one result if the agent is available or not. I would like more informations.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use [simple checks](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.0/manual/config/items/itemtypes/simple_checks) instead.